# How can I make my code extendable for future use

Tags: c#

I am trying to structure my code so that I can easily extend it in the future, however I think I am overthinking things and struggling to accomplish this.

My scenario is:
Based upon some data being passed to me I need to generate a class.
The class that I need to generate is not similar in nature to any of the other classes.

For example I have several classes that can be created:

```
public class File1{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   // etc...
} 
public class File2{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   // etc...
} 
public class File3{
   public string MyType {get;set;}
   // etc...
}
```

In my main class I have:

```
switch (myExtension)
            {
                case ".abc":
                    ProcessABC(myContents);
                    break;
                case ".def":
                    ProcessDEF(myContents);
                    break;
                case ".ghi":
                    ProcessGHIL(myContents);
                    break;
               //etc...
            }
```

I have tried creating an interface with a common method:

```
public ProccessStuff(data);
```

but I don't think that will work since I don't have a common return type.

Then I thought about an abstract class, but then it seems I'll be pushing a lot of work into that abstract class.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass 
{
    public void ProcessStuff(string data)
    {
        // Parse the data into an object

        // Update some DB fields

        // Log some data
    }
}
```

Am I on the right path with just creating an abstract class to handle all of my logic?

Comment: what do you mean by: not a common return type?

Comment: If you don't have a common return type, why not return an interface also?

Comment: File1 a = ProcessABC(myContents);
File2 b = ProcessDEF(myContents);
File3 c = ProcessGHIL(myContents);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying the classes don't have any similarities. But that's not actually true - they all take a `string` to do some processing, and it's exactly this that you want shared between the classes.

Make an interface, `IDataProcessor` (or something). There, have a single method - `void Process(string)`. The file classes will implement the method in a way they require.

This changes your main classes `switch` to a simple

```
IDataProcessor actualDataProcessor = ...;

actualDataProcessor.Process(myContents);
```

Of course, you still need some way to create the proper `IDataProcessor` based on e.g. the extension. Depending on your exact needs, a simple `Dictionary<string, Func<IDataProcessor>>` might be quite enough. Otherwise, there's plenty of other ways to bind classes more dynamically if you so desire, or use an explicit factory class.

Comment: I believe that is the part that I was stuck.  I started off creating an interface, but all it accomplished for me was to modify my switch statements some. (i.e. case ".abc" IMyInterface myInterace = new File1(); myInterface.Process(data); )

Comment: @JDS Yup, but that's kind of unavoidable (though it can be "automated" with metadata or convention-based configuration etc.). The point is that only the factory (or the configuration) itself needs to know this - the rest of your code will always work with just the interfaces. And in the end, when you're dealing with anything *not* abstract, interfaces aren't going to help you anyway - if you need to read the data from the class later, you need to know the correct type in compile-time. Either make sure the interface pays rent, or drop it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using generics?
Here is an example :

```
public void Process<T>(string contents)
    where T : IProcessStuff, new ()
{
    // Common work to do here
    // ...

    // Specific processing stuff
    T t = new T();
    t.ProcessStuf(contents);
}

public interface IProcessStuff
{
    void ProcessStuf(string contents);
}
```